# How to not detect opening of files and folders in google drive changes api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am building an expressjs application using the google drive api that notifies the user whenever there is a file change in their google drive through webhooks. However, i am also receiving webhooks when i open/view a folder or a file, which is completely unnecessary. Is it possible to only receive webhooks whenever a new file is created or deleted in the drive? And if so, how do i do it?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using this endpoint https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch ?

Comment: @iansedano yep, I am using that endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There is no direct way unfortunately.

You will likely have to make another request once your app has been notified of a change. Its possible you may have to persist some data to compare with depending on what you need to do exactly. The watch endpoint, as you have seen, will notify you of almost every change, including views. So you'll need to find a way to filter these out.

If you are trying to get create/deleted times only then I would suggest taking the file id from the change notification and making a request to get the file metadata and seeing if the file was created in the last 5 minutes (or less) for example. You can speed this up by only getting the `createdTime` field for instance.

For deleted, you can either get the type of change directly from the change notification, but this will only notify you if you have deleted it *permanently* i.e. not in the trash. Trash events look just the same as the others. If you need trash notifications, it is going to be more complicated. There is a `trashed` attribute, but not a timestamp for it. If you need this then you will probably have to keep a snapshot of which files are trashed and then every time you get a request, check to see if the file that changed is now trashed.

### There is an active feature request for this

> #### [Support event type filtering for Changes watch channel](https://issuetracker.google.com/170797848)

Go and give it a ☆ to let Google know that you want this feature!